# How to fill a matrix pattern using autofill?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In a google sheet, I have some numbers in column A and in row 1.
I want to fill the matrix as follows:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | f(B1, A2) | f(B2, A2) | f(B3, A2) |
| 2 | f(B1, A3) | f(B2, A3) | f(B3, A3) |
| 3 | f(B1, A4) | f(B2, A4) | f(B3, A4) |

How can I achieve this?

If I autofill the first column vertically using first three values, it doesn't even identify that B1 is constant in the pattern.

Similarly for horizontal autofill, it doesn't identify that A2 is constant.